# How to build One-To-Many relationships within JSON API

Tags: json

I`m very new to JS/APIs/JSON.

I`ve got an API I built using deployd, a great tool that allows to to quickly set up an API.

My API called "app" has two resources `zips` and `people`. Each entry/object in `zips` has only one property `zipcode`. Each `people` has the properties name and phonenumber.

I want to figure out a way to have people be associated with various zipcodes. Either one or many if necessary. This would, as I understand, involve adding a property to `people` such as `assoczipcodes` and using a relationship model to indicate with zipcodes are related.

I've done some research [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/) about how a relationship is structured but I simply don't understand the syntax and format.

Q: What datatype is correct for `associzipcodes`?

Q: What do I enter into each `assoczipcodes` to indicate which `zips` are related?

Answer (score 3):

Cristik's answer appears to be outdated. According to the current documentation, you'd want to nest the relationship like this:

```
{
    "type": "people",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
       "name": "John Doe"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "zipcodes": {
            "links": {
                "self": "http://myserver.com/people/1/zipcodes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the contents from the [Resource Relationships](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-structure-resource-relationships) section, the simplest approach would be to return an URL for the relationship, and have that URL return all information needed:

```
{
    "type": "people",
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "links": {
        "zipcodes": "http://myserver.com/people/1/zipcodes"
    }
}
```